# Client side file size end format validation. Why JS blocks files from being uploaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.validator.addMethod('accept', function () { return true; });
</script>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create","My controller",FormMethod.Post,new {enctype = "multipart/form-data"})) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input type="file" id="File" name="File" accept="image/*" />
        </div>
```

I cannot upload a file with JS turned on (when I click submit a yellow frame appears around file input and nothing more happens).

When I turn off JS my form submits.

With the 3 lines on top, the file upload form magically works with JS. I found these in one of my projects, but I cannot remember what they do or why they are needed.

Can you explain this to me?

**EDIT**

The whole code for the view.

```
@using EDoctor.Properties
@using EDoctor.Resources
@model EDoctor.Models.DoctorProfileViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.validator.addMethod('accept', function () { return true; });
</script>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create","DoctorProfiles",FormMethod.Post,new {enctype = "multipart/form-data"})) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>DoctorProfiles</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Model.PhotoFileUrl)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input type="file" id="File" name="File" accept="image/*" />
            @Html.ValidationMessage("UploadFile")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Model.LicenseNumber)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Model.LicenseNumber)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Model.LicenseNumber)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Model.FirstName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Model.FirstName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Model.FirstName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Model.LastName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Model.LastName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Model.LastName)
        </div>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Model.UserId)

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have turned off validation for file types. By default, html file types have an attribute *accept* certain types of files. The `Accept` field governs what file types are allowed.

```
$.validator.addMethod('accept', function () { return true; });
```

by adding a validation method that always returns true (`success`). The result is that any file type

Comment: What does this 'accept' stand for? Why are the other fields still JS-validated (having this validaor line included). (Client side errors are displayed e.g.  for text input)

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a model property that is marked as required, but it's not on the form anywhere. I see this:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Model.PhotoFileUrl)
```

and this

```
@Html.ValidationMessage("UploadFile")
```

in your form, but this is the markup you use for your file element:

```
<input type="file" id="File" name="File" accept="image/*" />
```

So it seems likely that your model has a `[Required]` attribute on a `UploadFile` field. This would likely trigger the unobtrusive validation, since the validator wouldn't be able to find the field to validate.

Comment: The only required field is LicenseNumber. UploadFile error message comes form controller ( ModelState.AddModelError("UploadFile", ex.Message);). Without this label: (@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Model.PhotoFileUrl)) it's still the same :(

Comment: @gisek, Tieson, see my updated answer. Accept field deals with allowable file types.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of Dave and Tieson I finally solved it and got a nice client side validation. I case somebody also needs to perform client side file validation I'll post here a detailed description:

**General ideas**

- MVC/jQuery doesn't understand **accept="image/*"** the way you expect it to. It doesn't accept *.png e.g.
- Unless you add **@Html.ValidationMessage("file_input")** there will be no place to display the error message. In consequence all you get is a yellow frame around the field (chrome) or nothing and a big WTF on your face when you try to submit your form.
- **@Html.ValidationMessage** generates the following html:

  ```
  <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="file_input" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
  ```
- jQuery validator will insist on placing it's own validation message if it finds the line above in html.

What if we want to validate image format and size on the client side and get a custom/localized validation message? We probably can use some kind of plugin, but you can also do this like that:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    <input type="file" id="file_input" name="file_input" onchange='validate_image_upload(this)' accept="image/*" class="fileToUpload" data-error-msg-max-size="@string.Format(ErrorMessages.FileSizeExceedsMaxSize,Settings.Default.OfficialMaxFileUploadSizeMBs)" data-error-msg-file-format="@string.Format(ErrorMessages.IncorrectImageFile, Settings.Default.AcceptableImageFormats)" data-max-size="1500000" data-acceptable-formats="@Settings.Default.AcceptableImageFormats"/>
    @Html.ValidationMessage("file_input[custom]")
</div>
```

**Please note adding '[custom]' to 'file_input' in ValidationMessage**

We do this to cheat jQuery and prevent it from putting it's own validation messge. (If you don't change it, jQuery will have no mercy and slaughter your own message). We still get the nice, original, MVC styled error message and can use Razor to generate it. We only have to somehow set it's content. This can be done by adding the following code on top of your View file (under other script tags):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.validator.addMethod('accept', IsFileValid);
</script>
```

What happens now?

- We ignore jQuery's strange ideas of accepting image files by injecting our own method (IsFileValid)
- jQuery still wants to put it's own validation message if IsFileValid returns false. But it has no place to to put it (we added '[custom]' to ValidationMessage) and now it generates the following html:

  ```
  <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="file_input[custom]" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
  ```

and jQuery is looking for

```
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="file_input" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

- It finds nothing, so it just highlights the input field and blocks submit button. (nice, half of the work is being done for us)
- All we have do to now is put our own validation message, which can be done by this script. (IsFileValid will handle everything so you don't have to do anything more than mentioned above).

  ```
  function IsFileValid(value, field) {
      return validate_image_upload(field);
  }

  String.prototype.format = function () {
      var s = arguments[0];
      for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length - 1; i++) {
          var reg = new RegExp("\\{" + i + "\\}", "gm");
          s = s.replace(reg, arguments[i + 1]);
      }

      return s;
  };

  function validate_image_upload(field) {
      var isValid = validate_image_size(field) &&
          validate_image_format(field);

      if (isValid)
          remove_error_message(field);
      else
          append_error_message(field);

      return isValid;
  }

  function validate_image_format(field) {
      var ext = $(field).val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
      var acceptabelExtensions = $(field).data("acceptableFormats").toLowerCase().split(',');
      if ($.inArray(ext, acceptabelExtensions) == -1) {
          var msg = String.prototype.format($(field).data("errorMsgFileFormat"), acceptabelExtensions.join(', '));
          append_error_message(field, msg);
          return false;
      } else {
          return true;
      }
  }

  function validate_image_size(field) {
      if (field.files[0].size > $(field).data("maxSize")) {
          append_error_message(field, $(field).data("errorMsgMaxSize"));
          return false;
      } else {
          return true;
      }
  }

  function append_error_message(field, msg) {
      var f = $(field);
      var sib = f.siblings();
      $.each(sib, function (i, v) {
          var name1 = $(v).data("valmsgFor");
          var name2 = f.attr("name") + "[custom]";
          if (name1 == name2) {
              $(v).attr("class", "field-validation-error");
              $(v).text(msg);
              return;
          }
      });
  }

  function remove_error_message(field) {
      var f = $(field);
      var sib = f.siblings();
      $.each(sib, function (i, v) {
          var name1 = $(v).data("valmsgFor");
          var name2 = f.attr("name") + "[custom]";
          if (name1 == name2) {
              $(v).attr("class", "field-validation-valid");
              return;
          }
      });
  }
  ```

**Remarks**

- Script validates file extension and file size
- It shows/hides validation message (finds this **file_input[custom]** and maps it to **file_input**)
- IsFileValid method is also hooked to onchange of the file input (so it displays na error immediately if you choose a bad image)
- Max file size and accepted file extensions are passed through a view from settings. (see the input tag).
- Validation messages are passed through a view form resources - so can be easily localized (see the input tag)
- Of course it's not safe. It's just user friendly. Remember to perform server side validation as well.

Hope I saved someone a few hours. :)